# header in react navigation bottom tabs

Tags: javascript, react-native, header, react-navigation

Hi I am creating an app with react native and I am using react navigation for the menu but I find a problem and now when I create a menu with bottom tabs a header is also created and it gives me a problem for that reason I would like to know how I can solve it this or disappear the header

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIH7Q.jpg)

mi code is

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function HomeStackScreen() {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const SettingsStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function SettingsStackScreen() {
  return (
    <SettingsStack.Navigator>
      <SettingsStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      <SettingsStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
    </SettingsStack.Navigator>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsStackScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try adding an option to one of your screens to hide the header. Either the Tab.Screen(s) or one of the Stack's Screen(s) ─ it's up to you based on your use case.

For example:

```js
...
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsStackScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

This way you don't have two nested headers appearing at the same time.

React Navigation even recommends this from their docs when nesting navigators.

> When nesting multiple stack, drawer or bottom tab navigator, headers from both child and parent navigators would be shown. However, usually it's more desirable to show the header in the child navigator and hide the header in the screen of the parent navigator.

> To achieve this, you can hide the header in the screen containing the navigator using the headerShown: false option.

Reference: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#nesting-multiple-navigators

Answer (score 0):

To take effect in all tabs, this works best;

```
...
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: "#000",
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsStackScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```